# regex nagative assert does not work in Linux 'find' command with regextype being 'sed'

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, find

Say I want to match files where the second digit doesn't equal 0.

e.g.

```
./update110000.pt -> match
./update170000.pt -> match
./update100000.pt -> not match
```

so I wrote this

```
.*update[0-9](?!0)[0-9]{5}.pt
```

which passed the regex check on https://www.regexpal.com/

But when I use the find command on Linux like below it doesn't work anymore

```
find . -regextype sed -regex '.*update[0-9](?!0)[0-9]{5}.pt'
```

I also tried adding backslashes but didn't work either

```
find . -regextype sed -regex '.*update[0-9]\(?!0\)[0-9]{5}.pt'
```

I know that in this case I could simply use

```
find . -regextype sed -regex '.*update[0-9][1-9][0-9]{4}.pt'
```

which actually worked. But I still wonder how to properly use the `(?!x)` syntax in the find command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the regex flavor as `sed`, it is actually [**POSIX BRE**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) that does not support lookarounds (you have a negative lookahead `(?!0)` in your pattern) and also follows some specific escaping rules:

```bash
find . -regextype sed -regex '\(.*/\)\{0,1\}update[0-9][1-9][0-9]\{4\}\.pt'
```

*Details*:

- `\(.*/\)\{0,1\}` - an optional sequence of any text and then `/`
- `update` - a fixed string
- `[0-9]` - a digit
- `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit (this is instead of the lookahead)
- `[0-9]\{4\}` - four digits** (note `4` here, not `5`)
- `\.pt` - a `.pt` string.

If you use [**POSIX ERE**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), you can avoid overescaping:

```bash
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '(.*/)?update[0-9][1-9][0-9]{4}\.pt'
```